# GCC throws error upon compilation: error: unknown type name ‘FILE’

Tags: c, gcc

I am making a function which is just writes `"hello"` to a file. I have put it in a different file and included its header in the program. But gcc is giving an error namely:

> `error: unknown type name ‘FILE’.`

The code is given below

`app.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "write_hello.h"

int main() {
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("new_file.txt", "w");
    
    write_hello(fp);
    
    return 0;
}
```

`write_hello.h`:

```
void write_hello(FILE*);
```

`write_hello.c`:

```
void write_hello(FILE* fp) {
    fprintf(fp, "hello");
    printf("Done\n");
}
```

when compiling by gcc the following occurs:

```
harsh@harsh-Inspiron-3558:~/c/bank_management/include/test$ sudo gcc app.c 
write_hello.c -o app
write_hello.c:3:18: error: unknown type name ‘FILE’
 void write_hello(FILE* fp) {
```

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` from `write_hello.c` as well. `FILE` is defined in `stdio.h`.

Comment: I noticed that you are calling the gcc compiler from the command line using sudo. There is no need to use sudo to compile files. It is best practice to remove this and simply type: gcc app.c

Answer (score 20, accepted):

FILE is defined in stdio.h and you need to include it in each file that uses it. So write_hello.h and write_hello.c should both include it, and write_hello.c should also include write_hello.h (since it implements the function defined in write_hello.h).

Also note that it is standard practice for every header file is to define a macro of the same name (IN CAPS), and enclose the entire header between #ifndef, #endif. In C, this prevents a header from getting #included twice. This is known as the "internal include guard" (with thanks to Story Teller for pointing that out). All system headers such as stdio.h include an internal include guard. All user defined headers should also include an internal include guard as shown in the example below.

**write_hello.h**

```
#ifndef WRITE_HELLO_H
#define WRITE_HELLO_H
#include <stdio.h>
void write_hello(FILE*);
#endif
```

**write_hello.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "write_hello.h"
void write_hello(FILE* fp){
    fprintf(fp,"hello");
    printf("Done\n");
}
```

Note that when you include system files, the header name is placed within `<>`'s. This helps the compiler identify that these headers are system headers which are stored in a central place based on your development environment.

Your own custom headers are placed in quotes `""` are typically found in your current directory, but may be placed elsewhere by including the path, or adding the directory to your list of directories that the compiler searches. This is configurable within your project if you are using an IDE like NetBeans, or using the -I compiler option is building it directly or through a makefile.

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is "internal include guard"

Comment: ok I got it, thanks. But again and again using stdio.h in many files , does it mean that stdio.h will included more than once or does stdio.h also have the "internal include guard".Thanks

Comment: @HarshDave, Yes, stdio.h has an internal include guard, as do all the standard include files. The first time you include a header, it defines the guard and includes its contents. The second time, the guard is already defined and so the #ifndef is false, and the entire header is skipped over. This is done by the C preprocessor, cpp, before gcc's compiler ever sees it. So stdio.h only gets included once per compile unit.

Comment: @ScottK, Thank you sir.