# Best way to test C++ global variables in gtests

Tags: c++, global-variables, googletest

I have a global variable that is configured with a function. I am writing a gtest to test if the function is working, by checking if the global variable changes after the function is called.

In **main.cpp**:

```
bool flag{false};
void FlipFlag() {
    flag = true;
}
```

In **main.h**:

```
void FlipFlag();
```

In **main_TEST.cpp**:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "main.h"

TEST(MainTest, TestFlagFlip) {
    EXPECT_FALSE(flag);
    FlagFlip();
    EXPECT_TRUE(flag);
}
```

How do I access the variable `flag` for testing? I do not want to declare `flag` in `main.h`. Is this the best way to test the flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a leaf from the answer in [Unit Testing C With Functions Not in Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531419/unit-testing-c-with-functions-not-in-header), one way is to use `extern` in a private header file that is only used by the gtest. So in addition to the files declared in the question above, there will be an additional header file, `main_pi.h` that declares `extern bool flag`.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to `main.h`:

```
extern bool flag;
```

This tells the linker that `flag` exists somewhere, and will resolve it at link time.

> The name can be referred to from the scopes in the other translation units.

*.cpp files are "translation units".

Here's [some documentation about extern](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

Comment: Whether what you're doing is a good idea or not is out of scope of this answer. ;)

Comment: I don't want externs, the same way I don't want to declare flag in main.h, for security purposes.

Comment: @bunbun You're sorely mistaken if you think that not declaring a variable will prevent malicious entities from accessing it.

Comment: @Brian I guess I just want to know if there are better ways to go about it, like if gtest has some way of testing global variables. Declaring variables in H files do open up legitimate concerns which I would want to avoid.

Comment: "Declaring variables in H files do open up legitimate concerns" - How so? This should only be a concern if you're releasing a library and also releasing the header files. To the final compiled executable, the location of the line of code in a header or source file makes no difference. You're question is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: And even so, this "flag" is going to be in memory somewhere, and someone who is determined can change that value without your knowledge.

Comment: Some variables don't need to be called outside of the implementation as they are relevant only to that specific scope. It just seems incorrect to declare an extern variable just for the sake of testing, and I wonder if there is a better way. Agree about the XY problem, edited my question to hopefully better explain my concern