# How to get gcov results for included C/CPP files

Tags: c++, c, include, gcov

I'm trying to get gcov results on a file that's brought in via `#include`. If I compile with it as a separate object file it works fine. For example with these files:

lib.h

```
int addFive(int num);
```

lib.c

```
#include "lib.h"
int addFive(int num)
{
   return num + 5;
}
```

testlib.cpp

```
#include "lib.h"
int main()
{
   return addFive(2);
}
```

If I then compile like so:

```
g++ -c -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage lib.c -o lib.o
g++ -c testlib.cpp -o testlib.o
g++ lib.o testlib.o -lgcov -o testlib
```

then I will get a gcda file as expected:

```
[~]$ strings testlib | grep gcda
/home/user/lib.gcda
[~]$
```

But if I attempt this when including the .c file like below

test.cpp

```
#include "lib.c"
int main()
{
   return addFive(2);
}
```

And compile that

```
g++ test.cpp -lgcov -o test
```

Then I don't get the gcda as expected:

```
[~]$ strings test | grep gcda
[~]$
```

Is there a way to get the gcda to show up when including a C file? The same applies to including a .cpp.

Comment: Did you run and get .gcda files? Did you `gcov test.cpp`? Did you get a `lib.c.gcov` and examine it? This all seemed to work fine for me. That said using `#include "lib.c"` is generally not a good idea. What's wrong with linking it?

Comment: If I run the first case `testlib` it does generate `lib.gcda`. If I run `test` it does not. I have to do `#include "lib.c"` in order to do a unit level test that accesses and exercises internal functions of the C file that aren't available to the end user, as described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531419/unit-testing-c-with-functions-not-in-header). I am ultimately seeking to see how well the test code covers the original lib.c file.

Comment: No, it won't generate `lib.gcda` in the second case. Just `test.gcda`. It's by translation unit, not by file. In the second case, you have one translation unit, not two.

Comment: The first example does generate `lib.gcda`. I just figured out if I compile `test` with `--coverage` instead of `-lgcov` it does generate a `test.gcda`. This will then generate `test.cpp.gcov` and `lib.c.gcov` after running `gcov` - is there a way to combine this `lib.c.gcov` with a separate black-box test that creates its own separate `lib.c.gcov`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I compile test with `--coverage` instead of `-lgcov` it does generate a `test.gcda`. I thought at first this was not what I wanted since I'm looking for coverage in `lib.c`

But if I run both `testlib` and `test` and then use gcov on all the files together, it combines the coverage data properly:

`gcov lib.gcda lib.gcno test.gcda test.gcno`

And this yields `lib.c.gcov` with code coverage from both test runs.