# Homework program that reads input from another file in C

Tags: c, sqrt

> For this lab, you are to write a a program that will first read in the
>   heights and weights of a series of people from a file named 
>   values.dat.  Create this file using your editor so that each line
>   contains a height and corresponding weight.  For instance, it might
>   look likea:

```
60.0  125.0
48.0  100.0
```

and so on.

Next creating a file called stats.h which includes the following:

```
#define MAXNUM 100
typedef struct person
{
  double height;
  double weight;
} Person;

//prototypes follow:
numPeople = getData(File *input, Person[] people, int MAXNUM);
getAverages(Person[] people, double *aveHeight, double *aveWeight, int numPeople)
getStandardDevs(Person[] people, double aveHeight, double aveWeight, 
                      double *stdHeight, double *stdWeight, int numPeople);
```

The main program will then look something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stats.h"

void main(void)
{
  char filename[] = "values.dat";
  FILE *input;
  Person people[MAXNUM];
  int numPeople;
  double aveHeight, aveWeight, stdHeight, stdWeight;

  numPeople = getData(input, people, MAXNUM)
  fclose(input);
  getAverages(people, &aveHeight, &aveWeight, numPeople)
  getStandardDevs(people, aveHeight, aveWeight, &stdHeight, &stdWeight, numPeople)

  printf("The average height is %lf\n", aveHeight);
  printf("The average weight is %lf\n", aveWeight);
  printf("The standard deviation of the heights is %lf\n", stdHeight);
  printf("The standard deviation of the weights is %lf\n", stdWeight);
}
```

Now, write the functions `getData`, `getAverages`, and `getStandardDevs`.
Put them here after the main program.

The formula for the standard deviation of a series of numbers x[1], x[2] ... x[n] is

```
std = sqrt( sum( (x[i] - xbar)**2 ) / (n-1) )
```

where xbar is the average value of x, n is the number of samples,
and **2 means squared.

Remember that to use sqrt, you must `#include <math.h>` and also
add -lm to the compile line.

The text above is the lab, when I try to create the 3 files (values.dat, stats.h, and the main program) I get an error right off the bat when trying to compile using, -gcc -o lab6 lab6.c -lm

The code I have right now for the main program is

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "stats.h"

void main(void)
{
  char filename[] = "values.dat";
  FILE *input;
  Person people[MAXNUM];
  int numPeople;
  double aveHeight, aveWeight, stdHeight, stdWeight;

  numPeople = getData(input, people, MAXNUM)
  fclose(input);
  getAverages(people, &aveHeight, &aveWeight, numPeople)
  getStandardDevs(people, aveHeight, aveWeight, &stdHeight, &stdWeight, numPeople)

  printf("The average height is %lf\n", aveHeight);
  printf("The average weight is %lf\n", aveWeight);
  printf("The standard deviation of the heights is %lf\n", stdHeight);
  printf("The standard deviation of the weights is %lf\n", stdWeight);
}

int getData(File *input, Person[] people, int MAXNUM)
{

}

double getAverages(Person[] people, double *aveHeight, double *aveWeight, int numPeople)
{

}

double getStandardDevs(Person[] people, double aveHeight, double aveWeight, double *stdHeight, double *stdWeight, int numPeople)
{


}
```

I Added the functions and tried to compile.

Is the line that I used to compile correct using -lm at the end of the line.
If anyone can help me to get this to compile using the three files that would be awesome, or if anyone can help with any of the code.

**Errors that I am getting**

```
In file included from lab6.c:4:0:
stats.h:9:9: error: unknown type name ‘File’
 getData(File *input, Person[] people, int MAXNUM);
         ^
stats.h:9:31: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘people’
 getData(File *input, Person[] people, int MAXNUM);
                               ^
stats.h:10:22: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘people’
 getAverages(Person[] people, double *aveHeight, double *aveWeight, int numPeopl
                      ^
stats.h:11:26: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘people’
 getStandardDevs(Person[] people, double aveHeight, double aveWeight,
                          ^
lab6.c: In function ‘main’:
lab6.c:14:15: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getData’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   numPeople = getData(input, people, MAXNUM);
               ^
lab6.c:16:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getAverages’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   getAverages(people, &aveHeight, &aveWeight, numPeople);
   ^
lab6.c:17:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getStandardDevs’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   getStandardDevs(people, aveHeight, aveWeight, &stdHeight, &stdWeight, numPeop
   ^
lab6.c: At top level:
lab6.c:25:13: error: unknown type name ‘File’
 int getData(File *input, Person[] people, int MAXNUM)
             ^
lab6.c:25:35: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘people’
 int getData(File *input, Person[] people, int MAXNUM)
                                   ^
lab6.c:30:29: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘people’
 double getAverages(Person[] people, double *aveHeight, double *aveWeight, int n
                             ^
lab6.c:35:33: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘people’
 double getStandardDevs(Person[] people, double aveHeight, double aveWeight, dou
                                 ^
```

Thanks

Comment: "I get an error right off the bat when trying to compile"  --  ***What is the error you are getting?***

Comment: There are a lot of errors. here are the first 3 
```
In file included from lab6.c:4:0:
stats.h:9:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
 numPeople = getData(File *input, Person[] people, int MAXNUM);
 ^
stats.h:9:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘numPeople’ [-Wimplicit-int]
stats.h:9:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getData’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 numPeople = getData(File *input, Person[] people, int MAXNUM);

```

Comment: please [edit] your question and add your errors to the question body.  Comments are transient and don't format properly.  Without knowing the errors you are getting, troubleshooting why your code doesn't compile is virtually impossible.

Comment: sorry, just added them all.

Comment: have you added `#include <stdio.h>` to every file that uses `FILE`?  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42744341/2495283

Answer (score -1):

`File` is not the same as `FILE`. The `<stdio.h>` defines `FILE` which is what you should be using.

I do not know if fixing this error (change your `File` references into `FILE` everywhere) will get you to compile as there may be other errors that are hidden by this one. However that would be the first error to fix towards making your code ompile.